# Unable to display JSON data with Angular interpolation

Tags: arrays, json, angular

In my Angular app, I'm trying to display data from the below JSON:

```
conversations: [
{
  'conversationdId': 1,
  'conversationTitle': 'My first convo',
  messages: [
    {
      'messageId': 1,
      'messageText': 'Hi'
    },
    {
      'messageId': 2
      'messageText': 'Hello'
    }
  ]
},
{
  'conversationdId': 2,
  'conversationTitle': 'My second convo',
  messages: [
    {
      'messageId': 1,
      'messageText': 'asdfasdfasdf'
    },
    {
      'messageId': 2
      'messageText': 'qwerqwerqwer'
    }
  ]
}
];
```

I've tried the following HTML:

```
<h2>
  {{conversations[0].messages[0].messageId}}
</h2>
```

But I'm getting this error in the console:

> TypeError: _co.conversations is undefined
>   Stack trace:
>   View_ConversationsComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/ConversationsComponent.ngfactory.js:11:9

What am I doing here that's incorrect?

Comment: Where you fill `conversations` array? inside `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: that's not a valid json though

Comment: also use safe navigation operator {{conversations[0]?.messages[0]?.messageId}}

Comment: also you are not assigning any values use `=`  instead of `:`

Comment: please check the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: @JoelJoseph When I replace _:_ with _=_, I get an error: **property or signature expected**

Comment: @user7554035 that's because you are not assigning a valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you missed the comma after `'messageId': 1` and you also need to initialize data inside the `ngOnInit` method so that you won't get this error.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  conversations;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.conversations = [
      {
        'conversationdId': 1,
        'conversationTitle': 'My first convo',
        messages: [
          {
            'messageId': 1,
            'messageText': 'Hi'
          },
          {
            'messageId': 2,
            'messageText': 'Hello'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'conversationdId': 2,
        'conversationTitle': 'My second convo',
        messages: [
          {
            'messageId': 1,
            'messageText': 'asdfasdfasdf'
          },
          {
            'messageId': 2,
             'messageText': 'qwerqwerqwer'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
 <h2>
  {{conversations[0].messages[0].messageId}}
</h2>
```

**[Here is demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4d1yo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

first run app
this variable is null or undefiend :conversations[0].messages[0].messageId

please declare or set *ngIf for this div

like this

```
<h2 *ngIf="conversations[0].messages[0].messageId">
  {{conversations[0].messages[0].messageId}}
</h2>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but I'm still getting the same error